# What is the most time efficient MySQL query for OneToMany mapping while ignoring some values?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have object Document. This document has OneToMany association to Property defined as so:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentDocument", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<CustomProperty> customProperties = new HashSet<>();
```

```
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Document parentDocument;
```

Object Document has some values I do not want to query, for example contents and many others. I could use JPA findAll method, but this takes too long because of above mentioned values. **How do I create query ignoring some, but not all values and also including subObject**(in this case CustomProperty) ? Also, the whole reason of this question is I am rewriting slow code. That is why performance is on my mind, so any performance advice is welcome !

I did try creating custom Query, defined so:

```
@Query("select new Document (d.id, d.title, d.customProperties) from Document as d)
```

This does compile, but does not work, **throws error**:
*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. as col_12_0_ from documents document0_ inner join custom_properties customprop' at line 1*
Query works without d.customProperties inside query.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @BillKarwin JPA/Hibernate does allow the creation of "Objects directly from the query", so to speak. It's called 'dynamic instantiation' and has been around since Hibernate 4.1 (To my knowledge). [Thorben Jensen has an article mentioning them](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-query-projections/#JPA8217s_DTOs) and [RedHat/Jboss have it documented](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/development_guide/the_select_clause_in_hql) as well (Sort of. It's pretty lacking IMO)

Comment: Show us the generated SQL.

Comment: generated query:
select document0_.id as col_0_0_, document0_.title as col_1_0_, . as col_2_0_ from documents document0_ inner join custom_properties customprop1_ on document0_.id=customprop1_.document_id

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
@Query("select d.id, d.title, d.customProperties from Document d")
```

Comment: Does not work :/
pretty much the same error.

Comment: Hi @MartinKršek  This might help

`@Query("select d.id, d.title, c.id from  Document d inner join CustomProperty on d.id=c.id")`

Also if you have multiple where clauses to fetch the data creating some index would also help you to optimize the query.

Comment: This returns array of arrays. Response looks like this:
[
    [
        "0001b17c-76eb-41dc-9b7d-e74ba646f7e9",
        "qJmJLdTG",
        "24d84c3a-0bcb-40bb-996d-a9b31accc078"
    ],
    [
        "0001b17c-76eb-41dc-9b7d-e74ba646f7e9",
        "qJmJLdTG",
        "4327c8cb-cc54-4f11-b0ed-a80547547e27"
    ]
]
And it should be like this:
[
   {
   "id": "0001b17c-76eb-41dc-9b7d-e74ba646f7e9",
   "title": "qJmJLdTG",
   "customProperty":
      [
      {"id": "24d84c3a-0bcb-40bb-996d-a9b31accc078"},
      {"id": "4327c8cb-cc54-4f11-b0ed-a80547547e27"}
      ]
   }
]